# PyQt5: how to do replacement using QRegularExpression

Tags: python, replace, pyqt5, qregularexpression

I want to reserve all English characters and replace others. When using 're' module, it looks like that:

```
name = 'srw  959we'
result = sub('/W', '', name)
```

Then I get `name = 'srwwe'`. Now I want to use the class QRegularExpression to realize that, but the [official document](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QRegularExpression.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QRegularExpression.swap:%7E:text=PySide2.QtCore.QRegularExpression.swap,very%20fast%20and%20never%20fails.) is so abbreviated that I found nothing useful. It will be appreciated if someone can give a brief and clear example for PyQt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done, because it requires the [QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) class, which is not included in PyQt (and the same goes for PySide). The equivalent to `re.sub` in Qt is [QString.replace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace-12), and there is just no way to access it from PyQt. (The [QRegularExpression.swap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html#swap) method does something entirely different, so is no help either).

`QRegularExpression` is only really useful in PyQt where you need to access a Qt API that requires passing an object of that type. For general string manipulation, just use Python's `re` module (or [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) if you need additional functionality).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and correction to my first post (not an English speaker XD). At the beginning, I want to avoid `import` other modules. Now I see that is inevitable. I will keep using `re` module to realize replacement.